# WebView evaluateJavaScript with backslash possible?

Tags: swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am currently trying to evaluate my javascript through my swift application. I am trying to insert a value to a `field` which is `"test\test"`. Unfortunately, when I add the backslash it does not appear and removes the second test word. Any ideas? Thank you!

**Code:**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {   
    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('_ValueTextBox').value = \"test\\test\"", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
        print("result \(result)")
        print("error \(error)")
    })
}
```

**Prints on websites textbox:** test

Comment: move your test\test into a variable and use it in the javascript function.

Comment: @Baam25 Thank you for your response! I tried this on my end unfortunately this didnt work for me. I tried with 4 \\\\ backslashes and that seem to do the trick!

Comment: why 4 I wonder....

Comment: @Harish i was confused too, Ballpoints answer helped me resolve this riddle. Thank you for your help as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one backslash, Swift would see `...value = "test\test"`, which means it sees a tab character instead of a backslash (and so does JavaScript). With two backslashes, Swift sees one backslash but JavaScript sees `...value = "test\test"` which means it still sees a tab character instead of a backslash. Four backslashes are needed so that the JS sees a backslash. Rule of thumb: for every additional level of nested interpretation of backslashes, you must double the number of backslashes you write in source, as each level reduces two backslashes to one.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, this answers my question as to why it worked when I added four slashes. Thank you again for your help!